# How to split a large file into many small files using bash?

Tags: bash

I have a file, say `all`, with 2000 lines, and I hope it can be split into 4 small files with line number 1~500, 501~1000, 1001~1500, 1501~2000.

Perhaps, I can do this using:

```
cat all | head -500 >small1
cat all | tail -1500 | head -500 >small2
cat all | tail -1000 | head -500 >small3
cat all | tail -500 >small4
```

But this way involves the calculation of line number, which may cause error when the number of lines is not a good number, or when we want to split the file to too many small files (e.g.: file `all` with 3241 lines, and we want to split it into 7 files, each with 463 lines).

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When you want to split a file, use `split`:

```
split -l 500 all all
```

will split the file into several files that each have 500 lines.  If you want to split the file into 4 files of roughly the same size, use something like:

```
split -l $(( $( wc -l < all ) / 4 + 1 )) all all
```

Comment: It is interesting to note that obtaining always the same number of files with “split -l” seems to me impossible, even if there are enough lines in the original set. Consider for example a set of 5 lines to split into 4 files. Asking to place 1 line per file will produce 5 files, not 4. Asking to place 2 lines per file will produce 3 files, not 4. "split -n" might be the correct way of doing that, if your version of "split" has it.

Comment: According to `man split` you can also do `split -n l/4` if you want 4 files of roughly similar size "without splitting lines/records"

Answer (score 10):

Look into the `split` command, it should do what you want (and more):

```
$ split --help
Usage: split [OPTION]... [INPUT [PREFIX]]
Output fixed-size pieces of INPUT to PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...; default
size is 1000 lines, and default PREFIX is 'x'.  With no INPUT, or when INPUT
is -, read standard input.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -a, --suffix-length=N   generate suffixes of length N (default 2)
      --additional-suffix=SUFFIX  append an additional SUFFIX to file names.
  -b, --bytes=SIZE        put SIZE bytes per output file
  -C, --line-bytes=SIZE   put at most SIZE bytes of lines per output file
  -d, --numeric-suffixes[=FROM]  use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic.
                                   FROM changes the start value (default 0).
  -e, --elide-empty-files  do not generate empty output files with '-n'
      --filter=COMMAND    write to shell COMMAND; file name is $FILE
  -l, --lines=NUMBER      put NUMBER lines per output file
  -n, --number=CHUNKS     generate CHUNKS output files.  See below
  -u, --unbuffered        immediately copy input to output with '-n r/...'
      --verbose           print a diagnostic just before each
                            output file is opened
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

SIZE is an integer and optional unit (example: 10M is 10*1024*1024).  Units
are K, M, G, T, P, E, Z, Y (powers of 1024) or KB, MB, ... (powers of 1000).

CHUNKS may be:
N       split into N files based on size of input
K/N     output Kth of N to stdout
l/N     split into N files without splitting lines
l/K/N   output Kth of N to stdout without splitting lines
r/N     like 'l' but use round robin distribution
r/K/N   likewise but only output Kth of N to stdout
```

Answer (score 4):

Like the others have already mentioned, you could use `split`. The complicated command substitution that the accepted answer mentions is not necessary. For reference I'm adding the following commands, which accomplish almost what has been request. Note that when using `-n` command-line argument to specify the number of chucks, the `small*` files do not contain exactly 500 lines when using `split`.

```
$ seq 2000 > all
$ split -n l/4 --numeric-suffixes=1 --suffix-length=1 all small
$ wc -l small*
 583 small1
 528 small2
 445 small3
 444 small4
2000 total
```

Alternatively, you could use [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
$ < all parallel -N500 --pipe --cat cp {} small{#}
$ wc -l small*
 500 small1
 500 small2
 500 small3
 500 small4
2000 total
```

As you can see, this incantation is quite complex. GNU Parallel is actually most-often used for parallelizing pipelines. IMHO a tool worth looking into.